# How to calculate the derivative of a function in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Properties) it is stated that the function
$$
f:\mathbb{Q}_p\to \mathbb{Q}_p
$$
with $f(x)=(1/|x|_p)^2$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is differentiable and its derivative is the zero-function.

> How can I see that? More generally, how can I derivate a function of $p$-adic numbers explicitely?

Comment: Aside: this is not actually a function $\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}_p$ because $|x|_p$ is a real number. This is a real-valued function of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition (yes, it's the same as in the general real case):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac1{|x+h|_p^2}-\frac1{|x|_p^2}}h=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{p^{2\nu_p(x+h)}-p^{2\nu_p(x)}}h=0$$

Since when $\;h\;$ is very close to zero, clearly both $\;x\;$ and $\;x+h\;$ are divided by the same power of the prime $\;p\;$ (which is what the $\;p-$adic valuation $\;\nu_p(x)\;$ gives) ...

Comment: You also need to check the derivative at 0...

Comment: Correction, @BenBlum-Smith : the OP needs to check it there. It is almost trivial as the valuation at zero is, by definition, zero.

Comment: I should have said, "one also needs..."

Comment: Actually, the case $x=0$ really needs the square in the function which I just added.