# derivative on $Q_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}_p\to \mathbb{R} $
with $f(x)=(1/|x|_p)^2$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ . How to prove that f is differentiable on $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

I am a beginner in this field  of p-adic numbers
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(p^{\nu_p(x+h)})^2-(p^{\nu_p(x)})^2}h$$
How to continuous?  because I did not understand this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547040/how-to-calculate-the-derivative-of-a-function-in-mathbbq-p)

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense: the limit as $h\to 0$ involves $p$-adic $h$ since you put $h$ into the function, but you are dividing a difference of function values by $h$ so you need $h$ to be real. This is inconsistent since most (small) $p$-adic numbers are in no meaningful way also real numbers.

Comment: @KCD can you see link , I repeat that I am a beginner in this field

Comment: You have to treat the *input* and *output* of the function as both being $p$-adic numbers, which is what it says in the question you link to in your post. For $x \not= 0$ in $\mathbf Q_p$, $|x+h|_p = |x|_p$ for all small enough $p$-adic $h$ (namely if $|h|_p < |x|_p$), so the function $f \colon \mathbf Q_p^\times \to \mathbf Q_p$ is *locally constant* and thus $f'(x) = 0$ since $f(x+h) = f(x)$ for all small $h$ (depending on $x$). You should try yourself to check $f'(0) = 0$: $f(h)/h \to 0$ in $\mathbf Q_p$ as $h \to 0$ in $\mathbf Q_p$.

Comment: Locally constant functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf R$ or $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf C$ do play an important role in number theory and representation theory (of $p$-adic and similar groups), but nobody talks about their "derivative" as an analogue of classical derivatives. If such a derivative had any meaning it probably should be zero, which makes the concept essentially useless.

Comment: In link , Ben Blum-Smith said This is a real-valued function of Qp. In the solution, I don't understand why the square has disappeared. my goal I'm looking for an example of a non-constant differentiable function on $\Q_p$.

Comment: Just because someone says something does not mean it must be "correct".  Naturally $p$-adic absolute values are interpreted as real numbers, but the $p$-adic absolute values of a $p$-adic number is just 0 or an integral power of $p$ and thus can be regarded as a $p$-adic number too (the rationals are inside $\mathbf Q_p$ and $\mathbf R$). Either way, the function $f$ you are looking at is *locally constant* and thus whatever notion of derivative you try to use is *uninteresting*.

Comment: Functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf C$ are important, such as characters, but those are locally constant so there is no worthwhile notion of derivative.  You differentiate functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf Q_p$, not real or complex-valued functions on $\mathbf Q_p$. Differentiable functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf Q_p$ are easy to write down: polynomials. I already explained in my first comment why the concept of derivatives for functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf R$ is meaningless. This is the last comment I am making on this question.

Comment: cerise, part of your confusion is justified because in the linked answer, they indeed forget the square. However, fixing that will not change the main argument; I will edit that there later. -- For a similar question and hopeful clarification see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608322/96384. The crux is that such a function *can* be seen as real-valued (in which case it has no derivative, but it is useful in other regards), or *can* be seen as $\mathbb Q_p$-valued (in which case it has a trivial derivative, and no other apparent uses.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, for the definition of a derivative to make sense, we need to view this as a function $f: \mathbb Q_p \rightarrow \mathbb Q_p$. Then

$$f'(x)=\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\begin{cases}\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{p^{2\nu_p(x+h)}-p^{2\nu_p(x)}}h \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ \displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{p^{2\nu_p(h)}}h = \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\lvert h\rvert_p^2 h} \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}.$$

Note that "$h \to 0$" here is meant in the $p$-adic sense, i.e. $\nu_p(h) \to \infty$, i.e. $\lvert h \rvert_p \to 0$.

Now in the first case, a fundamental principle of ultrametrics says that

$$\nu_p(x+h) = \nu_p(x) \text{ for all } h \text{ with } \lvert h \rvert_p < \lvert x \rvert_p$$

so that (since $x \neq 0$) we have $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{p^{2\nu_p(x+h)}-p^{2\nu_p(x)}}h = \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{0}{h} =0$.

(And the same would be true without the square: The absolute value function is locally constant away from $0$, hence has local difference quotient $0$.)

In the second case, we have $\lvert \dfrac{1}{\lvert h\rvert_p^2 h} \rvert_p = \dfrac{\lvert h \rvert_p^2}{\lvert h \rvert_p} = \lvert h \rvert_p$ and hence $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{\lvert h\rvert_p^2 h} =0$ as well. Note that without the square in the function, we would get $f'(0) =1$ here.

Comment: Thank you very much for those explanations